# Filter Alphabets from Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have input like :-

| Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 6 |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |
| 3 | Z |

And Output muse be

```
 Output
    A
    B
    C
    X
    Y
    Z
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a union followed by a filter:

```sql
SELECT val
FROM
(
    SELECT col1 AS val FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col2 FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(val, '^[A-Z]+$')
ORDER BY val;
```

Answer (score 0):

If data really looks as you put it, a simple option is to use `greatest` function.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'A', '4' from dual union all
  3     select 'B', '5' from dual union all
  4     select 'C', '6' from dual union all
  5     select '1', 'X' from dual union all
  6     select '2', 'Y' from dual union all
  7     select '3', 'Z' from dual
  8    )
```

Query:

```
  9  select greatest(col1, col2) result
 10  from test;

RESULT
----------
A
B
C
X
Y
Z

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```